# Dynamodb table design: nested query support

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb

We use AWS dynamodb for storing School details. Number of school entries may be too high in the future. so we preferred no-sql based storage.

We will get school details from different sources so the details we get from all sources are not of the same structure. For example, in few places we may get number of students and teachers. But in other sources we get only the location details.

So we thought of using "Overloading Global Secondary Indexes" concept.

Below is the table we use to hold the school details.

```
school name is partition key 
info type is sort key 
Attr1... AttrN is Details based on the info type.
```

Info type can have values like "Students info", "Teacher info", "Location info", "School board"

```
Partition key     infotype        Attr1            Attr2       Attr3  

schoolx           students        150           
schoolx           teachers        50 (permanent)   25 (Temp)
schoolx           Location        Delhi            India
schooly           students        25
schooly           Location        Mumbai
```

Index I created is for field "infotype"

Now we need to support query like following

1. Get the school names where students count is > 100
2. Get the school names where temp teachers count > 10 and located in Mumbai and has less than 100 students.
3. Get full details of the schools which has more than 50 teachers

Questions:

1. Does this design appreciated in Dynamodb (No-Sql)?
2. How do we support nested queries here in Query 2? Should i need to query 3 time and get common elements in 3 sets in code?
3. How do i get full details like Query #3? Should i need to query once again with the school name?

Answer (score 2):

**1**: Hmm that depends. Its not exactly good for a No-SQL pattern. But its not 'not doable'. The problem is denormalization of the data. SQL benefits of spreading(normalizing) data over multi tables and has ability to query with a flexible pattern. Like combining 'in Mumbai, less than 100'.

**2:** Lets say, you write all the attributes (teacher count, student count) next to Location like

```
Partition key     infotype        Attr1            Attr2       Attr3   StudentCount TeacherCount  

schoolx           students        150           
schoolx           teachers        50 (permanent)   25 (Temp)
schoolx           Location        Delhi            India
schooly           students        25
schooly           Location        Mumbai                                25          180
```

this means you can just query the `Location` GSI with the sort key of `Attr1` Mumbai and with the filter of `StudentCount > 10`, `TeacherCount > 125` (these attributes must be projected to the GSI). Its a one query. Read Capacity Unit equals to number of Mumbai items. Its less than 3 queries.

However, this denormalization comes with a write operation cost. Everytime these attributes changes you both need to change `Teachers` and `Location` items. 2 writes per one update.

All this was meant to explain, you gotta consider your access patterns and frequencies when deciding on TRADE-OFFS. If you are attributes are soo less, under 1KB then this job gets easy because you can project attributes and update freely without increasing the costs too much. There are many more factors to include. You have to work on it considering everything possible.

3: In fact, you have to query more than once. Because first query will return 'schoolx, schooly ..' and you have to query each of these individually to get their details.

Comment: Great answer from CanSahin. To keep the model flexibility of DynamoDB and also support your query needs I would suggest complement your DynamoDB table with another AWS services. If budget permits you could create a simple RDS instance and using DynamoDB Streams and Lambda populate this RDS database assync. You then first query this RDS instance to get the hash keys for the criteria and then consult DynamoDB in a BATCH_GET_ITEM operation. Another alternative could be using CloudSearch, but I think that this alternative would cost a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks @CanSahin. So in my questions if i want to add one more condition (total 3 conditions) like residing in Mumbai and student count > 100 and teachers count < 50, I need to duplicate all the attributes to all rows. This does not make sense. After going thro your response we thought of exploring Postgres performance for the same use case with more than Million records.

Answer (score 0):

GSI Overloading may not be the best option for this use case.  I would suggest just building one item using three updates, creating a regular GSI on City, and 3 write sharded GSI's on Students, PermanentTeachers, and TempTeachers.

Update will insert a new item if it does not exist so the first writer will create the item and the next two writers will just add their data to it.

The City GSI will never contain more than a few hundred items per Partition Key and they are all fairly small so the risk of a Hot Key is negligible.  When the query includes the City name you can hit that index and use Filter Conditions on Students and Teachers to get the correct result set.

The Student and Teacher GSI's probably need to be write sharded since they will query across all schools in the table.  To do this add a "GSI_Key" attribute to each item when it is inserted containing a random integer between 0-N and use that as the Partition Key for those GSI's.  To get the schools matching your criteria query all 0-N partitions in parallel with the appropriate Sort Key condition for the index, e.g. "students > 100", "tempTeachers > 25".  Add filter conditions for additional criteria as required.

The value of "N" for the GSI_Key attribute is determined by the rate at which items are added to the table and the size of the result sets that we expect to generate based on the Sort Key conditions the GSI's are queried with.  If you are managing all schools in India and bulk loading then you may have 50K items or more.  The items are small but will need to be updated several times so each item will cost 3 WCU to insert so you will need 150K WCU to write all these items to the table.  DynamoDB allows 1K WCU per Partition, so to ingest all those items in 10 seconds we will need 15 partitions for the write sharded GSI's.